# 16, 06, 68, 88, ?, 98

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, number-sequence, sequence

Can you figure out the rule that goes in this sequence?

16, 06, 68, 88, ?, 98

What is the '?' in the sequence?

Hint:

> the '?' does not have to be a number

Comment: I think you can delete yourself

Comment: @Wen1now No need to delete duplicates necessarily. This one has the benefit of having the numbers in text form, so someone googling may find this and then get directed to the linked version.

Comment: @Alconja how would I tell if it a duplicate before I post it? I would prefer not to get voted down :P

Comment: @NL628 Yeah, you probably wouldn't have found it if you didn't already know it was there, since the other version was image based, which kind of proves my prior point that there's no harm in duplicates. It's unfortunate you copped the down vote though since it's not a "bad" question, just a duplicate, but that's what closing/linking is for (I've +1'd to balance the rep loss out)...

Comment: @Alconja I see, thank you so much anyways! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems

> If rotate "16, 06, 68, 88, ?, 98" 180 degrees, it's "86, ?, 88, 89, 90, 91".
>  So ? is 87, and rotate it 180 degrees, all I can figure out is L8.